# How to check XAMPP's version on Windows?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

In Linux, its simple. I just type */opt/lampp/lampp status*, and it tells me about the XAMPP version.

```
Version: XAMPP for Linux 5.6.35-0
Apache is running.
MySQL is running.
ProFTPD is running.
```

What is the equivalent command for XAMPP on windows?

Comment: Dont you just look at the Control panel

Comment: I want to know a simple command line way to do that. I am not the admin of the Windows server. But if Control Panel can also be used, can you tell me where to look there?

Comment: Open readme_en.txt in the xampp installation path.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the Control Panel actually tells you maybe it's just the version number of the CP rather than the whole of XAMPP since I've got **XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.2** on the CP and **ApacheFriends XAMPP Version 7.1.14** in the readme...

Answer (score 32):

Open XAMPP Control Panel, hit on the "Help" button and then "View ReadMe" ... It'll open a Notepad file having the first line as:

"###### ApacheFriends XAMPP Version x.y.x ######"

where x.y.z is the XAMPP version!

Comment: Button is broken and doesn't open anything for me. XAMPP is so bugged

Answer (score 8):

Go to uninstall software if you are on windows and there you will see the version of your xammp.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

From the XAMPP control panel, beside MySQL module, click "Stop", then click "Start", then click on "Logs" and scroll to the last entry. The last line will read something like this:
2018-09-27 10:38:04 17812 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.31-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution

Awkward - but the only way I found to do this.

Comment: This specifies the database server version, not the xampp version.

Answer (score 6):

My XAMPP version is 3.2.4 and you can find the version of your xampp at the top of its control panel.

To check the version of xampp components:

1. For Apache:

   - Go to where you installed xampp and open xampp folder.
   - Travers through the following folders:

> xampp -> apache -> bin -> Right click on httpd.exe -> Properties
>   option         -> Details tab

- Check the File Version as displayed in the following screen:
  [image]

  2. If you want to use XAMPP shell, go to your xampp control panel and press Shell button in black at the right, after it opens 
     type the following commands to check the version for each apache, php and mysql:
- for Apache type : `httpd -v`
- for PHP type : `php -v`
- for mysql type : `mysql --version` , and that will display your MariaDB version too.

Comment: All three ways do not provide the version information for XAMPP itself, only for the different components

Comment: You can find the XAMPP version at the top of its control panel.

Comment: To add to comment by @NicoHaase and to answer your comment here, that is again version of another component of XAMPP, not XAMPP itself. That component is control panel itself.

Answer (score 5):

The version of Xampp package is also in the properties.ini file, not just in the readme.

Content **properties.ini**:

```
C:\xampp>type properties.ini
type properties.ini
[General]
installdir=C:\xampp
base_stack_name=XAMPP
base_stack_key=
base_stack_version=7.3.23-0
base_stack_platform=windows-x64
...
```

Content **readme_en.txt**:

```
C:\xampp>type readme_en.txt
###### ApacheFriends XAMPP Version 7.3.23 ######

Important! PHP in this package needs the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable package from
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/. Please ensure that the VC++ 2015 runtime
libraries are installed on your system.

  + Apache 2.4.46
  + MariaDB 10.4.14
  + PHP 7.3.23 (VC15 X86 64bit thread safe) + PEAR
  + phpMyAdmin 5.0.3
  + OpenSSL 1.1.0g
  + ADOdb 518a
  + Mercury Mail Transport System v4.63 (not included in the portable version)
  + FileZilla FTP Server 0.9.41 (not included in the portable version)
  + Webalizer 2.23-04 (not included in the portable version)
  + Strawberry Perl 5.32.0.1 Portable
  + Tomcat 7.0.106
  + XAMPP Control Panel Version 3.2.4.
  + XAMPP mailToDisk 1.0 (write emails via PHP on local disk in <xampp>\mailoutput. Activated in the php.ini as mail default.)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just go to the Xampp installation directory(Default is C:\xampp) and open readme_en.txt for English information and readme_de.txt for German information.

Answer (score -1):

Hey it's very easy to find your mysql version.

When you opened the XAMP control panel, there is a tab named 'Shell'. Click it and
a command prompt will open and all you have to do is to type the command **mysql --version**

Thats it! you can see the version.